# Create a LevelSet from a point cloud

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, openvdb

I am fairly new to OpenVDB. Apologies in advance if this query sounds trivial.

I want to construct an implicit surface from a set of unorganized data points. I want to know how I can do it using OpenVDB.

The current way I am doing it is as follows: ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=i4bfBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA139&dq=reconstruction%20of%20surfaces%20from%20unorganized%20data%20points&pg=PA139#v=onepage&q=reconstruction%20of%20surfaces%20from%20unorganized%20data%20points&f=false))

1. Compute distance function on a rectangular grid to an arbitrary data set.
2. Find an initial surface for the gradient flow algorithm
3. Solve the time dependent PDE for the level set function

I want to mention that I am just using a simple regular grid for the above three steps.

The example on creating and writing a grid from the code [examples](http://www.openvdb.org/documentation/doxygen/codeExamples.html) is very similar to what I want except that I want to replace the sphere's level set with a level set from the point cloud.

Is there a way that I can build a level set from utilities in the `tools` namespace to construct a level set from a point cloud? I see ParticlesToLevelSet as something similar to what I want to do. Can somebody kindly share an example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in finding the level surface of an unstructured point cloud.

The best thing I could find is this paper that describes an algorithm for doing it. The author also has other papers on the same topic. I haven't found any code that implements this type of algorithm though.

[https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~david/Papers/Linsen_TVCG.pdf](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/%7Edavid/Papers/Linsen_TVCG.pdf)